# Issue in carrying SVD on a large size matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I need to construct a lower-dimensional matrix $M$ of size $70,000 \times 70,000$ from a matrix of size $10^5 \times 10^5$ using SVD, discarding smaller singular values and the corresponding singular vectors.

I keep getting "out of memory" error.

Is it mathematically correct to split the matrix in two halves of size $50,000 \times 100,000$ each and carry SVD on individual halves and eliminate $15,000 \times 30,000$ from each by eliminating smaller singular values?

Comment: I don't think that this do-it-yourself makes any sense. How sparse is your matrix ?

Comment: Matrix is not sparse. But all entries in matrix are small of order 10^-8 to 10^-15.

Comment: If I am right, selecting the $70000$ largest SV and corresponding vectors will result in $2\times 70000$ vectors of length $100000$, which is more than your original data.

Comment: Do you call $10^{15}$ small ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It was a typing error. And also  I am not clear with what you asked. This is what I am doing. Lets suppose we need to create 50 x 50 matrix low size matrix. numpy.matmul(UU_E[0:50,0:50],Sigma_E[0:50,0:50]),numpy.transpose(VV_E[0:50,0:50]). The code is in python.

Comment: "Small values" is meaningless. You can rescale them. What matters is the distribution of the SV.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct, you have a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{100k\times 100k}$ and are trying to find a matrix $B\in \mathbb{R}^{70k \times 70k}$ with SVD. 
This is, as it's currently stated, impossible, as truncation of singular values will only reduce the rank of $B$, not the outer sizes.

You could, however, find $B\in \mathbb{R}^{100k \times 100k}$, with a rank as low as you want. To calculate an SVD is rather expensive (especially if interested in $U$ and $V$). 
One way to go around this is to calculate a non-optimal low-rank-optimization (by Adaptive cross approximation or random sampling or similar) and then orthogonalize the low-rank factors.

Comment: The reason I am eliminating the lower singular values is that, I want to reduce the condition number of the matrix in order to compute inverse. The method of adaptive cross approximation that you mentioned. Is it possible to reduce condition number using that.

Comment: By eliminating singular values, you do not reduce the condition number, you crank it up to infinity! The condition number of a linear function is given by $\kappa = \sigma_1 / \sigma_n$ with the singular values $\sigma$. By eliminating the singular values you set $\sigma_n$ to zero, and in turn set $\kappa = \infty$.

Comment: Can you please clarify, Because I think if I am truncating the U,S, V matrices. The lowest singular value of truncated matrix is higher than original matrix leading to reduction in condition number.

Comment: If you truncate any singular value, your matrix becomes singular and cannot be inverted. The subspace, that is not truncated, will always have an "okay" condition. 
What you can do, is finding an okay-conditioned Moore-Penrose inverse.